# How to use dynamic variable names in ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework

In my ionic app i watch a firebase path "game" which is copied in my local variable currentGame.
Example path:

```
this.gameProvider.currentGame.round2.character4.somevalue
```

I will have up to 10 rounds.
How can i do something like

```
for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
  console.log(this.gameProvider.currentGame.round + i + .character4.somevalue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```js
gameProvider = {currentGame:{}}

for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
  this.gameProvider.currentGame['round' + i ] = {character4: {somevalue: 'asdf'}};
}

for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
  console.log(this.gameProvider.currentGame['round' + i ].character4.somevalue);
}
```

Comment: perfekt answer! Thank you :-)